# Finding Bifurcation Point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

Consider $X' = AX$ where $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & 1 \\ 2a & 2 \end{pmatrix}$. For which values of $a$ do you find a bifurcation?

I attempted to solve this by finding the eigenvalues which I got $\lambda = 0, 2+a$ and corresponding eigen vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -a \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$. When I put these in canonical form I end up with $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2+a \end{pmatrix}$.

So I would think the only bifurcation point would be $a = -2$ because that causes the matrix to turn into the zero matrix. Otherwise, for any other value of $a$ you would essential have the same canonical form of the matrix. However, I plugged these equations into pplane graphing software and it seems as though there may also be a bifurcation point at $a = 0$ because the behavior is completely different. Is this because $0$ is another eigen value in the canonical form matrix? Are there any other bifurcation points that I should be aware of?

Comment: $0$ is certainly not an eigenvalue for all values of $a$

Comment: @Bryyo357: Are you sure you wrote the matrix properly? It almost seems that you meant for the top left value to be $a$ instead of $2$.

Comment: @Amzoti: You were correct, it was supposed to be $a$.

Comment: At $a=-2$ you get a stability transition, where $[1,2]^T$ switches from an unstable eigenvector to a stable eigenvector. (Also, you do *not* have the zero matrix in this case, you actually have a nondiagonalizable matrix instead.) What extra behavior are you seeing at $a=0$? It seems like it should not make a difference, it just aligns the eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$ with the $x$ axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are given $X' = AX$ where:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & 1 \\ 2a & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

We are asked to find the values of $a$ that produce a bifurcation.

The eigenvalues/eigenvectors are given by:

$$\lambda_1 = 0, v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -a \end{pmatrix}, \lambda_2 = a + 2, v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

The first eigenvalue is fixed as $\lambda_1 = 0$, so lets look at the second one.

For $\lambda_2 = a + 2$, we have three cases:

- $(1)$ the eigenvalue is positive for $a \gt -2$
- $(2)$ the eigenvalue is zero for $a = -2$
- $(3)$ the eigenvalue is negative for $a \lt -2$.

This tells us that there is a change in stability at $a = -2$ and that is our bifurcation point.

If we write the solution for this system, we have:

$$X(t) =  c_1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -a \end{pmatrix} + c_2 e^{(a+2)t} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Notice what happens to this solution at $a \lt -2, a = -2, a \gt -2$?

If we were to draw phase portrait movie by varying $a$ between $a \in (-3,3)$ in steps of $0.5$, we can see the stability transition (look at the direction arrows).

[image]

Note: at $a = 0$, we have nothing special.